# Using C++/CLI Utilities in .NET:

Tags: .net, pointers, c++-cli, wrapper

I've been developing some DLL utility projects to avoid having to repeat code throughout other projects, and also for features, algorithms and tests I haven't tried yet. One of those projects is in C++/CLI, language which I'm still learning, so this question may sound stupid. As I have Library Projects in C++/CLI, F# and C#, I use a C# console application to test them. It wasn't working with the C++/CLI Project, so I created a C++/CLI console test project. It never worked, and when I changed the name of the original DLL C++, the references weren't updated. When I (eventually) found out the problem, I changed the .vcxproj file, making the using directives possible, as for one method, but not for the template class `Apont<typename T>`, which is some kind of interior pointer, but that unlike the .NET type `System::IntPtr`, uses a value of the type `T*` instead of `void*`.

I also found out (from a post in this site) that I must use inside the project what I want to use outside, otherwise that stuff want be emitted in the metadata. So I have a useless static method in a static utility for that purpose:

```
static void Funcionalidades()
{
    int i = 10;

    Apont<int> a2 = Apont<int>(i);            // stack
    Apont<int> ^a3 = gcnew Apont<int>(i);     // heap CLR

}
```

Nonetheless, it doesn't work. Here is my main method in the C++/CLI test project:

```
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    int y(10);
    Apont<int> a = Apont<int>(y);

    Console::ReadKey();
    return 0;
}
```

And below are the errors (I know it can compile with intellisense errors, but I'll show them anyway):

```
error C2065: 'Apont' : undeclared identifier
error C2062: type 'int' unexpected
IntelliSense: identifier "Apont" is undefined
IntelliSense: type name is not allowed
IntelliSense: expected an expression
```

Why are these errors here? How can I correct them?

I'd appreciate any answer or reply.

### EDIT (clarifications):

- These errors DO NOT occur on the `Funcionalidades` method, that is in the DLL project, but on the main method, that is outside the DLL, in the test project.
- I'm writing everything in the header file; I mean not every header file has a respective .cpp file, although all headers are included in at least one .cpp file.
- More about `Apont`:

  - `Apont` is a template (because T* is used inside and "indirections on a generic type paremeter are not allowed").
  - `Apont` has a copy constructor, so `Apont<int> a = Apont<int>(someInt)` should work;
  - `Apont<int> a(someInt)` doesn't work;
  - `Apont` is some kind of interior pointer; and I didn't post the whole code because it isn't relevant, I'd have to translate varibles' names, and it may have errors I can easily fixed by me, but that would only distract you.

### NTH EDIT (where 'n' is a number I don't know):

`Apont`'s code you've been complaining about for so long:

```
    template<typename T> public ref class Apont sealed : public IDisposable
    {
        bool eliminado;
        T *pointer;

        /*void Dispose(bool tudo)
        {
            if (!eliminado)
            {
                if (tudo)
                {
                    ~Apont();
                }
                else
                {
                    !Apont();
                }
            }
        }*/
        !Apont() // finalizador: limpa os recursos "unmanaged"
        {
            delete pointer;
            pointer = nullptr;
            eliminado = true;
        }

    public:
        Apont(T &valor)
        {
            pointer = &valor;
            eliminado = false;
            ErroSeNulo = false;
            ErroSeEliminado = true;
        }
        Apont(T &valor, bool erroSeEliminado, bool erroSeNulo)
        {
            pointer = &valor;
            eliminado = false;
            ErroSeEliminado = erroSeEliminado;
            ErroSeNulo = erroSeNulo;
        }
        Apont(Apont<T> %outroApont)
        {
            this->pointer = &outroApont
        }

        property bool ErroSeEliminado;
        property bool ErroSeNulo;
        property T Valor
        {
            T get()
            {
                if (pointer != nullptr)             
                    return *pointer;
                else if (eliminado && ErroSeEliminado)
                    throw gcnew ObjectDisposedException("O objeto já foi pelo menos parcialmente eliminadao.");
                else if (ErroSeNulo)
                    throw gcnew NullReferenceException();
                else
                    return 0;
            }
        }

        /*
        Apont operator ~(/*T valor* /)
        {
            // este operador tem de ser declarado fora desta classe 
        }*/
        T operator !(/*Apont apont*/)
        {
            return Valor;
        }
        void operator =(Apont<T> outroApont)
        {
            pointer = outroApont;
            ErroSeEliminado = outroApont.ErroSeEliminado;
            ErroSeNulo = outroApont.ErroSeNulo;             
        }
        template<typename U> void operator =(Apont<U> outroApont)
        {
            pointer = safe_cast<T>(outroApont.pointer);
            ErroSeEliminado = safe_cast<T>(outroApont.ErroSeEliminado);
            ErroSeNulo = safe_cast<T>(outroApont.ErroSeNulo);
        }
        /*
        void operator =(T *&outroPointer)
        {
            pointer = outroPointer;
        }
        template<typename U> void operator =(U *&outroPointer)
        {
            pointer = safe_cast<T>(outroPointer);
        }*/
        void operator =(T *outroPointer)
        {
            pointer = outroPointer;
        }
        template<typename U> void operator =(U *outroPointer)
        {
            pointer = safe_cast<T>(outroPointer);
        }


        ~Apont() // destruidor: limpa todos os recursos
        {               
            this->!Apont();
        }

        // Error C2605: 'Dispose': this method is reserved within a managed class
        // O código será gerado automaticamente a partir do finalizador e do destrutor
    };

    template<typename T> Apont<T> operator ~(T &valor)
    {
        return gcnew Apont<T>(valor);
    }
```

Comment: Your question isn't really very clear - the one thing I picked up on is that you said *"I'm writing all the code in the header file"*, and then you have errors about *undeclared identifier* - so you *do* actually `#include` your header file don't you? Headers don't get compiled otherwise.

Comment: You should probably make a [short, self-contained, correct example](http://sscce.org/). Too many things missing or not stated in your question that would be necessary for an answer. I am sure you will get more replies if you follow the suggestions in the link above.

Comment: I am not even clear what your question is. The title is about C++/CLI utilities. Then, you mention some DLL  problems, then F#, then a template called Apont. It seems you believe you need a static method for some reason, and then you follow up with an incomplete example. In addition, you post a lot of information in the comments; is this information important? I do not know. In order to find the problem, you should reduce it as much as possible.

Comment: Also, what is this? Apont<int> a = Apont<int>(y); Just use Apont<int>  a(y);

Comment: All my comment replies are summarized in the clarifications edit, thus I'll remove all my comments.

Comment: Why the downvotes? I don't know what's going on in this piece of code, and instead of trying to help me you cowards downvote without an explanation? If you think it is confusing I may be able to clarify your doubts, so you can clarify mine; I just need an answer that solves and explains this.

Comment: The function names/signatures may be mangled in c++ when compiled even to dll, you will need to find what they are in the dll and create links to them  for example uncover the internal name from the dll via use of `link /dump /exports mydll.dll`.  Check that the values and functions you expect to be present are actually present in your dll with the link command I mentioned before.  Let me know how you get on and I will try and help you to get this resolved.

Comment: @GMasucci, I'm pretty new to C++, how can I use that? [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31d242h4.aspx) seems to be related, but how can I use it; is it in the Command Line? In a VS Tool? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi,  yep you use it from the command line.  id suggest navigating into the directory the dll is in and just using link /dump/exports mydll.dll rather than having to type the full path after the command:)

Comment: @GMasucci, I took a while getting it right, but the result I get is (where "\n" represents a line break): `File Type: DLL \n\n Summary: \n\n 1000 .data \n 14000 .rdata \n 1000 .reloc \n 3000 .rsrc \n 5000 .text`. What does this mean? None of them is the name of any function I wrote. What can I do? (Note: if you think this is awkward and want to check it ([the DLL in Skydrive](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=82256A0F5EE62D44!40548&authkey=!AEiw5rFiYR_KbHI)) yourself, I'd be very grateful; otherwise you could give me instructions by an answer, which I would also gratefully accept.)

Comment: I see, Just noticed some of my dlls are doing the same as well and had to turn off debug info ` Properties, Linker, Debugging, Generate Debug Info = No` so the names were not mangled.  and were correctly visible.   On a sidenote dumpbin.exe does a similar job (VS commandline) or [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) has a nice gui to it to achieve the same.  I am looking into this hidden function name problem as I have the same issue with some of my own dlls, however the functions are usable in vs when I import the dll...very strange.

Comment: `Utilidades.ComNativos` is the namespace I get looking at the dll, `Apont` is not exposed at all, however `UtilCMM` is, perhaps take a look at what differentiates these two classes? (starting point might be: apont is a sealed class, utilscmm is a static class)

Comment: @GMasucci, The namespace is right, `UtilCMM` is the static class with the method `Funcionalidades` to generate metadata. BTW, can you post your comments as an answer (and add an explanation for having to turn off debug info, if you may). I tried doing the command line thing again, but it failed with various errors (various times, various "solutions"). I have put the new file plus the projects in the question [here](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=82256A0F5EE62D44!40549&authkey=!AA3l_ByfkRTacvI)(note: by some reason the `Debug` folder of `ComNativos` is in the main solution folder).

Comment: @JMCF125 added an answer I think will solve the problem: templates are only evaluted at compilation so if there are no declared instances then no template class will be available via the dll.  See below for a better version.

Answer (score 3):

Your error as it appears is usually missing declaration of class. This usually happens then the code in header is header-guarded away.

**How does this happened?**

If you include Apont header inside Funcionalidades and then include Funcionalidades header in Apont than you're in trouble. That happens because Funcionalidades header is missing declaration of Apont in case you include Apont in your main before including Funcionalidades.

Then you include Apont first time, it will enable header guard. Then it will include Funcionalidades which includes Apont as well. Because header guard is already enabled Funcionalidades header will not have Apont declaration. At the same time Apont declaration didn't even started yet in corresponding header file of Apont. And here you are, can't compile because of this problem in main, because at library compiling you haven't such a dependencies.

**How do I fix it?**

Move usage of Apont inside Funcionalidades implementation in cpp code, keeping header file without dependencies.

Comment: that seems plausible, but I had already tried to move the implementation of `Funcionalidades` back and forth, and the place makes utterly no difference. There are also no infinite inter-references, the file that contains `Apont` doesn't refer the one that contains `Funcionalidades`. What makes me most angry is this short error without a piece of description of its cause across the projects. And I really though this answer as going to work. +1 for the effort and making me catch some more errors.

Answer (score 1):

It just complains that it doesn't know "Apont".  I don't know what it is either, you didn't post its code.  Just declaring an arbitrary version of it:

```
generic<typename T>
public ref class Apont {
    T value;
public:
    Apont(T init) : value(init) {}
};

static void Funcionalidades()
{
    int i = 10;

    Apont<int> a2(i);                      // stack
    Apont<int> ^a3 = gcnew Apont<int>(i);  // heap CLR

}
```

Note the altered code for "a2", avoid copy constructors for reference types.  Again in main:

```
    Apont<int> a(y);
```

Comment: I didn't include `Apont`'s code because I don't think it is relevant, and it is also likely to be filled with stupid errors I can solve on my own. Still, if you feel I should provide it, please ask below and I'll edit my post and insert it.

Comment: `Apont` is suppose to be some kind of interior pointer (only with an inside value of type `T*` instead of `void*`). Your version is some kind of wrapper.

Comment: Oddly enough, your version isn't working either! The errors are EXACLY   the same!

Comment: I posted tested code, it compiles fine.  Read the last paragraph of the answer.

Comment: I do not doubt it. I read the last paragraph, and did exacly what you said. I even (actually, I had already done) defined a copy constructor. It must be some problem in the project settings. Why is this happening? What should I do?

Comment: I don't know why you expect me to guess at this, I can't see your code from here.  Not making it available is pretty pointless.

Comment: there it is! Are you happy now? As you can see it is quite confusing and unorganized, with probably also a handful of boneheaded errors. This is why not maikng it available wasn't pointless.

Answer (score 1):

*I must use inside the project what I want to use outside*

If this is true, have you called the static function anywhere? Chances are the uncalled function might get optimized out.

Comment: that actually makes sense, but as the purpose of this function is to make other stuff available, if I had a function to make this one available, I'd need to have one more function for each function I had, that is, an infinite number of functions. The only way would be to do this in A Console project, where the `main` function is always called, as all the functions in it (unless there's some exception in the middle). However, how come are there C++ DLL's, if there's no `main` function to be called? Either you're wrong, or my compiler has a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be missing using statement for namespaces? Make sure you have the right using statement at your main method. Also make sure you have added a reference such that the project containing the main method references the project containing Apont.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but I already checked it all at least 5 separate times before posting this question, and 5 more afterwords.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for taking so long to get back to you:  I have a couple of points for you that should help to sort the problem out.
 - the template class is declared as [sealed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/0w2w91tf%28v=vs.100%29.aspx): this means you cant use it as a base class (opposite of your main reason for a templated class).  At the very least its not needed so it may be worth removing.
 - secondly, and more importantly, in C++ templates are evaluated at compilation time, so, as you have no specified instances declared theres no evaluation of Apont and its not compiled into the DLL. To enable specific versions of the template class you can, at the end of the `UtilCMM.h` file, add the following:

- `class template Apont<int>;`
- `class template Apont<float>;`
- `class template Apont<double>;`

This is due to the fact that in C++ templates are expanded by the preprocessor at compile time, much like macros, however only version which are explicitly used are processed at compilation time: this is a great strength and weakness both.  The solution as I have always found (in consensus with other C++ programmers) has been to either:

- explicitly instanciate the versions you need to export in the dll
- provide a header file with the template, which can then be utilised by who-ever you are distributing the code to

If there are other ways to achieve the same,  I have not yet encountered them, and would love to find out, alas these are the limitations of templates.

then when you compile you should have the three specific versions available.  Just add more for each type you wish to include in the DLL.  Sorry I didn't spot this earlier, they both leaped out when I saw the full code, Now if I can just get the project to compile I can try the changes myself (my version of VS does not load your version of vcproj files, typical).

Comment: I used `ref class template Apont<int>`, but unfortunately the errors remained in the test project. As I was tired of this I merged the DLL with the test project and it worked. I'll continue to try to fix it (I kept the original projects) and see if the merging actually changes something (I now have the "Dependency Walker" so I can see the emitted metadata). +1 for all the help, I'll try be back as soon as possible to the matter.

Comment: Anyway, I wanted `Apont` to be a template. That would be like having three classes for three types.